# Securing REST web service in GlassFish

Tags: web-services, authentication, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jersey

everyone.
I have a problem securing my REST web service. It's part of Java EE web application. To secure the pages I used login-config tag and set up "FORM" authentication. Now I don't know how to secure web services, because "FORM" is not appropriate for it and I can't have two login-config tags for app. I considered splitting into 2 apps, but don't think it's a good idea. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This has info on how to create secured web services using NetBeans: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/wsit.html

Many web service providers use an api key to authenticate access to the service.  You may want to consider doing something similar for your service.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty common for the REST API to have a separate subpath - that way you can specify the auth constraint just to the URL's specific to your application and for the URI's corresponding to your REST API implement authentication using jersey OAuth filter or something else.

In case your app is all written in Jersey and you would like to expose exactly the same URI's for REST clients as well as browser (and differentiate just based on the requested media type), you can have a "login" URL (for displaying a login page) and only that you could protect using FORM authentication. Then again you would add Jersey OAuth filter (or other auth filter) which would not kick in unless there is OAuth header in the request, and another filter where you would check if ContainerRequest.getUserPrincipal() is null. If it is null, you could return `Response.seeOther(UriBuilder.fromPath("/login").queryParam("redirect", request.getAbsolutePath()).build()).build()` - that will redirect to the login (for oauth this would not kick in, since either the oauth request would succeed, or the previous filter would fail and return Unauthorized or Bad Request status codes). In the login resource you can use the redirect query parameter to redirect back to the original page once successfully logged in.